# Protected shadow endpoints

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

How can we implement `SvelteKit` protected `shadow endpoints`?

I want my selected `shadow endpoints` to return the value if the `access_token` in the `cookies` is valid. So, I want to be able to check validity of the `token` before. How can we have it without using boilerplate code everywhere and still have security?

Answer (score 0):

A `RequestHandler` (a function exported by a [page endpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints)) receives (amongst other parameters) an http request. You could look inside that request to parse the cookies and validate a token stored inside them.

Here's an example using a fresh sveltekit project. It uses the [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) package to parse cookies from the headers:

in `src/routes/index.svelte` (a simple page that displays `responseData` returned by the endpoint):

```html
<script>
  export let responseData 
</script>

<h1>Protected shadow endpoint</h1>
<p>Protected endpoint data:</p>
<p>{JSON.stringify(responseData)}</p>
```

in the endpoint `src/routes/index.js`:

```js
import cookie from 'cookie'

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').RequestHandler} */
export async function GET({ request }) {
  let responseData = null

  // parse the cookies from the headers and get the token
  const cookies = request.headers.get('cookie')
  const token = cookie.parse(cookies)?.access_token
  console.log('token', token)

  // check token validity
  if (token === 'abcd') {
    responseData = { msg: 'hello world' }
  } else {
    responseData = { msg: 'invalid token' }
  }
  return {
    body: {
      responseData,
    },
  }
}
```

To experiment with this fairly simple solution, you could use a [hook](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks) to store a cookie in the upcoming requests to the index page.

> [The **[handle](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#handle)** function] *runs every time the SvelteKit server receives a request — whether that happens while the app is running, or during prerendering — and determines the response.*

In `src/hooks.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
  let response = await resolve(event)

  // you can change this value to see how it reflects on the index page
  const token = 'abcd'

  if (event.url.pathname === '/') {
    // add a token cookie to requests accessing the index page
    response.headers.set('set-cookie', `access_token=${token};Path=/;HttpOnly`)
  }

  return response
}
```